# Does PAAS need any Remote display?

Tags: remote-access

Does PAAS solutions need any Remote display like VNC ? I’m new to this and would like to know about a delivery solution which can minimize latency for interactive (especially video) content.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what kind of platform your PaaS provider offers you and what kind of application you'll place onto that platform.

Generally, the easiest solution these days would probably be to use a HTML5-capable web browser at the client side to display the content. A remote display functionality like VNC provided by the platform would generally be intended for the administration of your application only.

Of course, you're free to set up the server application to use some other protocol, which might require some specific type of client application.

Minimizing video latency is a tradeoff between distance, bandwidth and CPU power:

- More advanced codecs may reduce the bandwidth requirement, at the cost of needing more CPU power to encode/decode the video. Codecs may also need some number of video frames to analyze in order to achieve effective compression, effectively enforcing the minimum limit of latency.
- It'll be easier to achieve a high-bandwidth connection over a short distance than over a longer one. A cloud-based solution cannot necessarily achieve as small a latency as an on-site one, simply because of the amount of links and hardware in between the server and the clients.
- As a result, trying to use a higher amount of CPU power available at a distant cloud provider can easily hit diminishing returns or even be counter-productive in terms of latency, depending on details of the situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its really helpful. Actually my client devices would be smartphones. I want to allow access to apps remotely so that users can run apps without downloading. Is remote display the answer? Or can i use some kind of application server that loads specific pages on client side?

Comment: A remote display protocol like VNC would definitely require loading a VNC client app to the smartphone. An application server that provides a webpage that can be used to launch a HTML5 video stream would probably be the most universally-functional solution with no client app requirements, assuming that you don't have to target old smartphones with no HTML5 capability. If you need to support older smartphones, then you would have to study what video streaming methods they have available, and what is needed to provide the right kind of stream for each type of phone.

Comment: I actually intend to build a client app where the users can go and launch the app. Do you think HTML5 is responsive enough ? And how do i get the a natively built app to display HTML5?